# Unity code to place object in particular position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to place an object in a particular position using unity. May I know how to do that on code? While starting, the object wants to present in one location, after that it should go to a particular location using drag drop. After moving to that particular location, I want to show log to check whether the position is correct or not. Can anyone help me please, thanks!

Comment: [`objectReference.transform.position = XYZ`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html)?

Comment: Actually the object want to place at between of two object and it should locked between those objects and want to give me the log.. could you help me

Comment: `objectReference.transform.position = (objA.transform.position + objB.transform.position) / 2f; Debug.Log(objectReference.transform.position)`

Comment: may i get a complete code .. im new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try drag drop technique for GameObjects which highlighted in this thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/drag-drop-game-objects-without-rigidbody-with-the-mouse.64169/

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{  
    private bool _mouseState;
    private GameObject target;
    public Vector3 screenSpace;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        // Debug.Log(_mouseState);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            target = GetClickedObject (out hitInfo);
            if (target != null) {
                _mouseState = true;
                screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (target.transform.position);
                offset = target.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z));
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
            _mouseState = false;
        }
        if (_mouseState) {
            //keep track of the mouse position
            var curScreenSpace = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z);

            //convert the screen mouse position to world point and adjust with offset
            var curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curScreenSpace) + offset;

            //update the position of the object in the world
            target.transform.position = curPosition;
        }
    }


    GameObject GetClickedObject (out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        GameObject target = null;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit)) {
            target = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Object want to placed in particlar location for example, the object is present in position of x:0.025,y:0.491 and z:-1.79 and it want to go to position of X:-3.28,Y:-0.5 and Z: -5.32 , if the object placed in this new location means i need a log using drag drop if its on some other location means no need to show me log

Comment: To be clear, does I correctly understood behavior?
1. object in position A
2. you move it via drag/drop to point B
3. if object after moving in predefined point C then log something, else - leave object in point B without action